# Understanding example of function that vanishes at infinity

Tags: real-analysis

> $X$ is a topological space and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ vanishes at infinity if for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{x:|f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$ is compact.

Looking at an example $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ define as
$
f(x)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & |x|<1 \\
      \frac{1}{|x|} & 1\leq |x| 
\end{array} 
\right. 
$

But $\{x:|f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$ is $(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)$ which is not compact?

Comment: That second condition in the definition of $f$ has got to be wrong. What's supposed to happen at -2?

Comment: Once you fix that, try an explicit value like $1/1000$ for $\epsilon$, and you'll see that you calculated the set incorrectly.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Ah I see, thanks for the comment. If I set $\epsilon =\frac{1}{1000}$ then since $f(x)\neq 0$ we have $\frac{1}{|x|}\geq \frac{1}{1000}\implies |x| \leq 1000$ I have the set is $[-1000,1]\cup [1,1000]$, which is compact. But I'm still a bit confused when epsilon is arbitrary, cant we take it to infinity?

Comment: The definition is that the set is compact *for each* $\epsilon > 0$. So even though we may take $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small, for any given $\epsilon$, the set is still compact, so everything is OK.

Comment: 1) @daisies is correct. 2) Once epsilon gets larger than 1, you get the empty set. So I'm guessing you're thinking of epsilon not going to infinity, but going towards zero, in which case the sets get larger, and expand "towards infinity".

Comment: 3) Speaking loosely, letting epsilon go to zero would correspond to taking an (increasing) union of the pre-image sets. Which you can do, but this just shows that an infinite union of compact sets need not be compact. The key is that for any particular epsilon, @daisies description holds.